# initCircularRegionWithCenter:radius:identifier: is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, ios7, core-location

I have the following problem on Xcode on this entry :

```
CLRegion *pushRegion = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:coordinate radius:[userInfo[@"aps"][@"radius"] doubleValue] identifier:pushIdentifier];
```

Xcode give me the message

> " 'initCircularRegionWithCenter:radius:identifier:' is deprecated:
>   first deprecated in iOS 7.0

I tried some variants found on this site, but nothing helps :(

Comment: Use `CLCircularRegion`. That's what says the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'CLCircularRegion' as mentioned in doc

```
CLCircularRegion *pushRegion = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(65.023, 24.032) radius:30.0 identifier:@"identifier"];
```